# Why doesn't the search feature work properly?

Tags: support

I am fed up of having my posts marked as duplicate, if the search feature worked properly and drew out relevant answers then I wouldn't have an issue but the fact is, I ask a question because those threads I have read prior to posting a question DON'T answer the question I ask yet I get a notice that I have made a duplicate post when I have not and in most cases this notice is slapped on my post that points to my previous question that has not been answered.

You need to add...

A button to allow the OP to indicate that the original question has not been answered, the user makes a post and an automatic link offered to be added to the post to allow people to see your previous question.

If like in my situation the question wasn't answered or partly answered and is not relevant, then that is not a duplicate and I am fed up of having to justify myself to anal moderators who don't like my questions as they were not well received. Well the answer is simple isnt it? If you don't like the question then you don't answer it do you?

So please sort your search out because I have read the how to ask questions and frankly I have been doing so for the most part for 48 years of my life to date. I am not a child and do not appreciate being treated as such.

I have written too long a complaint to the contacts and here in feedback and this is killing my fingers, I have early onset of arthritis in my hands, feet and spine, so sometimes I may come across as abrupt or grumpy but thats the nature of my medications.

So can we all move on now?

Comment: Rants don't get anything solved. So why don't you [edit] your question to include some examples so we have something to work with? I see 3 closed questions (and only two duplicates) out of 14 questions. Certainly nothing overwhelming there so without any examples of what you're talking about this is just a useless rant. And yeah.. the search isn't great. It's usually a better idea to use Google and add `site:askubuntu.com` to your query.

Comment: What is wrong with you people? This is not a rant. No chance of editing it either. SORT THE SEARCH FACILITY OUT, SIMPLE.

Comment: "What is wrong with you people?" "anal moderators" "SORT THE SEARCH FACILITY OUT, SIMPLE." "I am fed up of"... that makes the topic a rant to me though I do intend to answer ;)

Comment: None of your questions seem to link to what you have tried before, how am I supposed to know what you tried and didn't try if you don't say that in the question?

Answer (score 7):

> I  am fed up of having my posts marked as duplicate,

So they are correctly closed as a duplicate?  Then if so: I would ask myself: how did those users find the duplicates? Maybe it is worth  asking some of those people in chat or through a PM. I know I would answer you if you would have PM'd me.

It is unlikely they do it from memory. I consider 2 options to be possible:

- They are using the Ask Ubuntu search. I tend to use that if I want to search clean words, a specific user with some specific words, or tags.
- They are Using another search tool. I myself am very fond of the google "site:" option search.  Your start your search with "site:askubuntu.com" and the title of the Ask Ubuntu topic and you will see loads of topics with the same subject and probably a solution to your topic. Has anothe benefit: it will also show answers for topics that are not on Ask Ubuntu (like ubuntuforums or omgubuntu.co.uk or webupd8).

Maybe you are looking at it the wrong way: no search tool is going to beat google. So embrace it and use google search too :)

Comment: You might want to explain *how* to PM someone.. ;)